# Split Panel Text Inside Of A CSS Shape

Tags: css

Using HTML and CSS.

I have 2 sets of text. I want one on each side of the line inside of the diamond
the diamond is made completely from CSS along with the separating line inside of it.

Not really sure how to accomplish this. I tried aligning the text a certain way and I also tried floating the text but neither was successful.

Help is greatly appreciated.

```css
body{
  background-color: pink;
}

/*Developer Section*/
#developer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.diamond{
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 5px solid #65C8D0;
    background-color: #65C8D0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 300px; 
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.headshot{
    position: relative;
    z-index: inherit;
    background-color: black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #65C8D0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -850px;
}
.developer-inner{
    position: relative;
    color: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.headshot-text h1{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.split{
    width: 3px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!--Dev Section-->
        <section id="developer">
            <div class="diamond"></div>
            <div class="headshot"></div>
            <div class="developer-inner">
                <div class="headshot-text">
                    <h1>Lorem Lorem</h1>
                </div>    
                <div class="developer-about">
                    <div class="dev-panel-left">
                        <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="split"></div>
                    <div class="dev-panel-right">
                        <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex`:

```css
body{
  background-color: pink;
}

/*Developer Section*/
#developer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.diamond{
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 5px solid #65C8D0;
    background-color: #65C8D0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 300px; 
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.headshot{
    position: relative;
    z-index: inherit;
    background-color: black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #65C8D0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -850px;
}

.developer-about {display:flex; align-items:center}

.developer-inner {
    position: relative;
    color: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0 40px;
}

.headshot-text h1{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.split{
    width: 3px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<!--Dev Section-->
        <section id="developer">
            <div class="diamond"></div>
            <div class="headshot"></div>
            <div class="developer-inner">
                <div class="headshot-text">
                    <h1>Lorem Lorem</h1>
                </div>    
                <div class="developer-about">
                    <div class="dev-panel-left">
                        <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="split"></div>
                    <div class="dev-panel-right">
                        <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```